# Export a function in Makefile

Tags: function, makefile, export

I'd like to use a function in a recursive call of `make`.

I have the following in the principal Makefile:

```
define my_func
Hello $(1) from $(2)
endef
export my_func
```

And further, in another one called later, I have :

```
$(error my_func is $(call my_func,StackOverFlow,Me))
```

It gives me this output `Makefile_rec.mk:1: *** my_func is Hello  from .  Stop.`

But what I'd like is `Makefile_rec.mk:1: *** my_func is Hello StackOverFlow from Me.  Stop.`

Is there a way using `make` to export such a variable/function and get it to work when using `call` function ?

Thanks !

### -- EDIT --

As pointed by @Renaud Pacalet [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51319961/export-a-function-in-makefile/51321633?noredirect=1#comment89632872_51321633), I would like also to use this kind of macro either in the current Makefile and in sub-makes.

If possible, not by `including` a file each time I need the macro

Comment: Why not just put `my_func` in a separate `makefile` and [`include`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-include) it where necessary?

Comment: @G.M. This is a workaround yes, but it would be easier to maintain if I could just `export` it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want this to work you must double the `$` signs in your definition:

```
define my_func
Hello $$(1) from $$(2)
endef
export my_func
```

From the manual:

> To pass down, or export, a variable, make adds the variable and its
>   value to the environment for running each line of the recipe. The
>   sub-make, in turn, uses the environment to initialize its table of
>   variable values.

You must protect the `$` from one extra expansion.

Of course, you cannot use the same macro in the top Makefile. If it is a problem, you must define a macro for the top Makefile and another one for the sub-make Makefile:

```
host> cat Makefile
define my_func
Hello $(1) from $(2)
endef
my_func_1 := $(call my_func,$$(1),$$(2))
export my_func_1

all:
    $(MAKE) -f Makefile_rec.mk
    $(info TOP: $(call my_func,StackOverFlow,Me))

host> cat Makefile_rec.mk
all:
    $(info BOT: $(call my_func_1,StackOverFlow,Me))

host> make --no-print-directory 
TOP: Hello StackOverFlow from Me
make -f Makefile_rec.mk
BOT: Hello StackOverFlow from Me
make[1]: 'all' is up to date.
```

Comment: Damn ! Why didn't I try this before... Thanks soooo much. I didn't think that `export` would affect the actual value of a variable

Comment: It is not really export (even if it is about the same), it is make that expands the variable when invoking the sub-make.

Comment: It `make` sense then. That's a very interesting point to know

Comment: Based on your answer, I wanted to set a variable `VAR` with the result of `$(call my_func ...)` in the same Makefile, but I only get one expansion. I then have a duplicate of `my_func` inside `VAR`. Is that possible to force expansion ?

Comment: Use `$(eval VAR = $(call ...))`: `eval` expands its parameter before instantiating it as make construct. Then, make expands it a second time. It should work.

Comment: I have one `$(info ...)` and it gives `VAR=Hello $(1) from $(2)`. The `$(error $(VAR))` then outputs `defines.mk:56: *** Hello  from .  Stop.`.
And what i would like here is `VAR=Hello StackOverFlow from Me`

Comment: You're right, I've been a bit too fast on this. So, what you want is being able to use this same macro in the Makefile where it is defined and in another Makefile used by a sub-make invocation? Honestly, I am stuck here. We need help from a real make wizard. Mad Scientist, are you here?

Comment: I found a solution (see the updated answer) but, honestly, I don't like it. It's a bit too clumsy.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the `$(or)` builtin:

```
define my_func
    @echo Hello $(or $(1), $$(1)) from $(or $(2), $$(2))
endef
export my_func
```

From gmake man page:

> $(or condition1[,condition2[,condition3...]])
>
> The or function provides a “short-circuiting” OR operation. Each
> argument is expanded, in order. If an argument expands to a non-empty
> string the processing stops and the result of the expansion is that
> string. If, after all arguments are expanded, all of them are false
> (empty), then the result of the expansion is the empty string.